# Does the term "radiation" broadly include 'radioactive particles'?

Tags: terminology, definition, radiation, radioactivity

In the current context of the Ukranian situation, but also in past contexts like the Fukushima incident, the press warns that "radiation may spread into distant areas..." and so on.

As I understand it, "radiation" per se can't spread on the wind, but it's easy to see that as a shorthand or metonym for radioactive particles or other materials that may carry it.

Do informed persons (as in this community) use this shorthand as well, or is this strictly something from popular media?

Comment: I certainly understand it, and might use it depending on just what I wanted to convey. Seems fairly opinion based...

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think it really depends on context and opinion. In the context of most pure physics problems, though, "radiation" would probably refer either to electromagnetic waves or to elements of the atomic nucleus that are ejected from an atom (like alpha and beta particles). So it probably makes sense within the context of the news article, but I think it's fair to say that an unstable isotope being carried on the wind is not "radiation" in the strict sense.

Then again, it's possible that the article meant *the area over which radiation is being emitted* can spread. In this case it is certainly true, because as unstable isotopes spread across a larger area they will increase the radiation levels experienced by the people who live there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all technical-nit-picky, then *radiation* is energy (either as photons, or as the kinetic energy of massive particles) that "radiates" outward in straight lines from a source.

*Ionizing radiation* is radiation in which each individual photon or particle carries enough energy to break chemical bonds and cause chemical reactions.

*Radioactivity* is a property of certain nuclides that causes them to spontaneously emit ionizing radiation while simultaneously *transmuting* into a different nuclide. (E.g., "Cobalt-60 is intensely radioactive".)

And then, backing away from technical, nit-pickyness for a moment:

*Radioactivity* sometimes is informally used to describe the presence of radioactive material and, especially, radioactive *contamination.* (As in, "Whoa! Back off everybody. There is radioactivity here.")